# Pushing packages to a Python artifact registry repository

Tags: gcloud, google-artifact-registry, gcloud-python

what are ways to push packages to an AR Python repository? I tried to look at [the API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest), but only operation there I could find related to uploading a package, is the UpdateRepositoryRequest, which seems to update the repository with another.

As the repositories should be buckets, uploading to a bucket blob should be possibly but I wasn't able to achieve this. All errors related to bucket not being found. What would be the correct URL for a bucket corresponding to an AR repository?

I know the `gcloud` CLI tools allow for this quite easily (and I used it successfully), but I was wondering if there was any way to do it with the Python API?

Comment: Why do you want to do that with `Python` code ? You can upload your Python package in artifact registry with `python3` command line. It's the common way to publish a `Python` package to a repo (public or private)

Comment: I am writing a Python script for automation of a repository content update. To me having an upload feature in the API feels natural, seeing that a vast amount of other operations are supported regarding repository actions. But you are right, the `python3` command works and can be executed within a .py script, so that will be my initial approach.

Comment: If you are interested, I can propose you a clear answer for your question ? It can maybe help newcomers for this kind of need.

Answer (score 1):

To publish `Python` packages in `Artifact Registry`, you can check the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/store-python)

The package upload should be done with `python3` command line and `twine` as an usual `Python` package and private repo.

- Authentication with [keyring-backend](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#keyring)
- Install `twine` :

```bash
pip install twine
```

- Build your `Python` package
- Upload the packages to the repository from your `dist` directory :

```bash
python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://us-central1-python.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/quickstart-python-repo/ dist/*
```